# Measure to sum a column for each row where another column is non-empty, and accumulate this sum over time

Tags: sql-server, powerpivot, dax

The following measure is close to what I want to do. It sums rows based on their value in the EmploymentLevel and accumulate over time.

```
FullTimeEquivalentEmployeesStarted:=CALCULATE(SUM([EmploymentLevel]);FILTER(ALL(tDates[Date]);tDates[Date]<=MAX(tDates[Date])))
```

In addition to what the measure above does I also want rows in tEmployees to be excluded if they have a blank value in the column [DateStarted]:

I have tried the following measure, but it doesn't work as intended. When I add the second filter, the one on tEmployees, the measure for some reason no longer accumulates over time. I don't know why.

```
FullTimeEquivalentEmployeesStarted:=CALCULATE(SUM([EmploymentLevel]);FILTER(ALL(tDates[Date]);tDates[Date​m]<=MAX(tDates[Date]));FILTER(tEmployees ;(tEmployees [DateStarted])<>BLANK()))".
```

I am writing this measure in the calculation area beneath tEmployees if that is relevant.

Can you help me figure out how this measure should be written to work as intended and described in the question title?

```
FullTimeEquivalentEmployeesStarted:=?
```

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between tDates and tEmployees? I copied your formula exactly and I get a running total with tDates[Date] on the Rows of the pivotTable, appropriately filtering out blank DateStarted Employee rows.

Comment: I put a relationship between DateStarted and tDates[Date], perhaps this isn't correct?